# Problem with adding a cookie to a selenium python script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The task is to perform parsing of the site. You need to get the phone number after clicking on the "show number" button. The first part of the script goes to the page, gets the cookies. The second part adds these cookies to the driver, it is assumed that this action will remove the popup window agreeing to accept the site cookie. Then the script is executed. The problem is that I get an error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: invalid cookie domain

Then I attach the code itself and a saved cookie that specifies the domain:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json

url = 'https://auto.ria.com/uk/auto_audi_q5_34319384.html'

def get_page_cookies():
    # options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    # # options.add_argument('--headless')
    # options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    # driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    # wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    # driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    # driver.get(url=url)
    # cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    # with open('cookietest.json', 'w', newline='') as outputdata:
    #     json.dump(cookies, outputdata)
    # print(cookies)
    ################################################################
    with open('cookietest.json', 'r', newline='') as inputdata:
        cookies = json.load(inputdata)
    cookielist = cookies[0]

    options_with_cookie = uc.ChromeOptions()
    #options_with_cookie.add_argument('--headless')
    options_with_cookie.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    driver_with_cookie = uc.Chrome(options=options_with_cookie)
    driver_with_cookie.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    driver_with_cookie.add_cookie(cookielist)    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver_with_cookie, 10)
    driver_with_cookie.get(url=url)
    show_number_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
'#floatingButtons > div:nth-child(1) > a')))
    show_number_button.click()
    phone_number = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
'#phonesBlock > div > a')))
    print(phone_number.text)

    driver_with_cookie.quit()
    # driver.quit()

 get_page_cookies()
```

Cookies:

```
[{"domain": ".ria.com", "expiry": 1682492766, "httpOnly": false, "name": "_gid", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "GA1.2.701191873.1682406366"}, {"domain": ".ria.com", "expiry": 1682409966, "httpOnly": false, "name": "AMP_TOKEN", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "%24NOT_FOUND"}, {"domain": ".ria.com", "expiry": 1682406426, "httpOnly": false, "name": "_dc_gtm_UA-110070444-1", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "1"}, {"domain": ".ria.com", "expiry": 1690182366, "httpOnly": false, "name": "_fbp", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "fb.1.1682406366193.2002288764"}, {"domain": ".ria.com", "expiry": 1716966365, "httpOnly": false, "name": "ui", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "a560f2fb72dfc405"}, {"domain": ".auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1682492765, "httpOnly": false, "name": "PHPSESSID", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "rOUzz7pTfuacuo991aJIjq0acDVM0scB"}, {"domain": "auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1684998365, "httpOnly": false, "name": "showNewNextAdvertisement", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "10"}, {"domain": "auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1685084765, "httpOnly": false, "name": "slonik_utm_source", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": ""}, {"domain": ".auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1682406965, "httpOnly": false, "name": "__utmt", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "1"}, {"domain": "auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1685084765, "httpOnly": false, "name": "slonik_utm_medium", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": ""}, {"domain": ".auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1682406965, "httpOnly": false, "name": "__utmt_b", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "1"}, {"domain": ".ria.com", "expiry": 1716966366, "httpOnly": false, "name": "_ga", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "GA1.2.1163034090.1682406365"}, {"domain": ".auto.ria.com", "httpOnly": false, "name": "__utmc", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "79960839"}, {"domain": ".auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1698174365, "httpOnly": false, "name": "__utmz", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "79960839.1682406366.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)"}, {"domain": ".auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1682408165, "httpOnly": false, "name": "__utmb", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "79960839.2.10.1682406366"}, {"domain": "auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1685084765, "httpOnly": false, "name": "slonik_utm_campaign", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": ""}, {"domain": ".ria.com", "expiry": 1690182365, "httpOnly": false, "name": "_gcl_au", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "1.1.519219103.1682406365"}, {"domain": ".auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1716966365, "httpOnly": false, "name": "__utma", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "79960839.1163034090.1682406365.1682406366.1682406366.1"}, {"domain": ".auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1684998365, "httpOnly": false, "name": "showNewFeatures", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "7"}, {"domain": "auto.ria.com", "expiry": 1682492766, "httpOnly": true, "name": "PHPSESSID", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "eyJ3ZWJTZXNzaW9uQXZhaWxhYmxlIjp0cnVlLCJ3ZWJQZXJzb25JZCI6MCwid2ViQ2xpZW50SWQiOjI3NzQ1OTQyOTksIndlYkNsaWVudENvZGUiOjE5MjcyNjczMzMsIndlYkNsaWVudENvb2tpZSI6ImE1NjBmMmZiNzJkZmM0MDUiLCJfZXhwaXJlIjoxNjgyNDkyNzY2MTYyLCJfbWF4QWdlIjo4NjQwMDAwMH0="}, {"domain": ".ria.com", "expiry": 1716966365, "httpOnly": false, "name": "_ga_KGL740D7XD", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": false, "value": "GS1.1.1682406365.1.0.1682406365.0.0.0"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to add a cookie in Selenium that belongs to a different website than the one you're currently visiting, Selenium will throw an error called "InvalidCookieDomainException." For example, if you fetched cookies for "https://test.com" but you're trying to add them to "https://test.org" in your Selenium script, you will get this error.

In WebDriver, you can only set cookies for the current website you're visiting. If you try to add cookies to a different website, this error will happen. Additionally, if the website you're trying to add cookies to doesn't use a secure connection, such as "http://" or "ftp://," you may also get this error.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. I forgot to prescribe :

```
driver_with_cookie.get(url)
```

перед

```
driver_with_cookie.add_cookie(cookielist)
```